# leaflet.js map not showing with meteor.

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

This is the code that I have in my js file.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.map.rendered = function(){
  var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  var osmAttrib='Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors';

  console.log("RENDERED CALLED");
  var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib});   
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.3, 0.7),9);
  map.addLayer(osm);
};
}
```

This is my html -

```
<head>
```

WhatsGoingOn

```
<body>
  {{> map}}
</body>

<template name="map">
  {{#constant}}
      <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  {{/constant}}
</template>
```

I looked at the page in console - the template is being appended, and there are leaflet dom elements. However, I can't see a map.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try put your library under client/compatibility ?

Answer (score 0):

Set map `height` properly. For example:

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="height: 100px;"></div>
```